# Can I define variables as arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following use of jQuery UI function:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function () {
        var hasHiddenList = $(this).children('ul.hidden');
        if (hasHiddenList.length)
            hasHiddenList.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    out: function () {
        var hasEmptyList = $(this).children('ul.empty');
        if (hasEmptyList.length)
            hasEmptyList.addClass('hidden');
    },
    drop: function () {
        var hasEmptyList = $(this).children('ul.empty');
        if (hasEmptyList.length)
            hasEmptyList.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

And I am wondering if I can define the variables `hasHiddenList` and `hasEmptyList` outside the callback functions, since it is the same variable in all of them.

Comment: Why don't you just try? :)

Comment: But you just do e.g. $(this).children('ul.hidden').removeClass('hidden'); ... no need for the length check

Comment: @Robin just because it would be legal code doesn't make it good design.

Comment: @Jack thanx, missed it :) but still, if I needed the variables what would be the correct way to to it, to keep `this` pointing to the current `.droppable`?

Comment: @IlyaD No, that wouldn't make sense because 'this' is not defined outside of those event handlers.

Comment: @Jack but I can pass it as a part of the arguments object, right? so is there a way to access it without modifying the `droppable` function?

Comment: I suppose in the big scheme of things, functions are also variables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, really want the variables, there are two options.

The obvious one (with pitfalls) is this:

```
var hasHiddenList = $('.droppable').children('ul.hidden');
var hasEmptyList = $('.droppable').children('ul.empty');

$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function () {
        if (hasHiddenList.length)
            hasHiddenList.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    out: function () {
        if (hasEmptyList.length)
            hasEmptyList.addClass('hidden');
    },
    drop: function () {
        if (hasEmptyList.length)
            hasEmptyList.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

Variables have been extracted, the code is less repetitive. All good.

Now, the problem is that the selectors are just run once. The callback `over`, `out` and `drop` are called every time one of those events occur, but `hasHiddenList` and `hasEmptyList` will not have been updated; they will still be the same thing between every invocation. Probably not what you want.

The way to remedy this is to use functions instead of variables, like this:

```
var hiddenList = function(target) {
    return $(target).children('ul.hidden');
};
var emptyList = function(target) {
    return $(target).children('ul.empty');
};

$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function () {
        var list = hiddenList(this);
        if (list.length)
            list.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    out: function () {
        var list = emptyList(this);
        if (list.length)
            list.addClass('hidden');
    },
    drop: function () {
        var list = emptyList(this);
        if (list.length)
            list.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

This abstracts away how the queries are performed (you only have to write `$(target).children('ul.empty');` once instead of twice) but in reality the code has not really become simpler. Actually, I would even say that it's harder to follow it now. On the other hand, if you were using the same selector even more than twice, lets say five times, then maybe this would actually be useful.

Also, note that I've removed "has" from the variable names, because "has" makes it sound like they are booleans, which they are not. They are lists of elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer :) In this case of course I will use the first version without the variables, but I wanted to know how to pass variables like that

Answer (score 5):

Better yet, you don't even need the if-statements and the variables:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    over: function () {
      $(this).children('ul.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    },
    out: function () {
      $(this).children('ul.empty').addClass('hidden');
    },
    drop: function () {
      $(this).children('ul.empty').removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

Comment: and, more relevantly, don't even need the variables!

Comment: @Jakob if I know those selectors might come back empty, isn't it better practice to do the whole `if` check?

Comment: And I'm sorry but this isn't the answer to what I asked. If I wanted to keep the variables, what would it be possible to declare them outside the callback functions?

Comment: To the first question: I'd say no, because the code is needlessly complicated. jQuery already makes the check for you, no need to do it twice. Also, it's always the case that a selector can come back empty, so being explicit about that doesn't really add anything.

Comment: I'll add another answer, explaining how you could do it if you really want the variables.

Comment: @Jakob why not just add it to this answer? :)

Comment: @Jack: because in my opinion the second answer is an "incorrect" one and will bloat the simple point of the first one.